# passing command line arguments in perl

Tags: perl, command-line-arguments

I have trouble in assigning an argument value / command line arguments. Here is what i actually want to do.

```
Test.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl

#Variable declaration

$RUN_DIR="/home/ckhau/database/experiment/test";
    #Main program

$index=-999; 
#my $ARGV;
@files = <$RUN_DIR/b*.txt>;

foreach $file (@files)
{
 #$SCRIPT="perl abcdinfo.pl $file";
 $SCRIPT="perl abc.pl $file";
 system("$SCRIPT");       
}
```

I tried replacing b*.txt with @ARGV and tried running the program i.e when i replace the above code with

```
@files = <$RUN_DIR/@ARGV>;
```

Then try to run with command line

```
perl Test.pl b*.txt
```

This gives me an error perl: no match. Can anyone help me on the following.

How to use command line argument for this ???

Can i use these kind of syntax in command lines "b*.txt" or "r_*.txt"???

Comment: This probably has to do with the fact that shell doesn't handle * in the command line arguments very nicely.

Comment: What shell are you running this script in? Windows command prompt? Linux bash shell?

Comment: @Jonah Bishop : i am using linux

Comment: Please show the code that actually has the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shell is trying to expand `b*.txt` to the list of matching files in your current directory. Once your program receives those values, your `glob` looks like

```
@files = </home/ckhau/database/experiment/test/b1.txt b3.txt b3.txt>
```

which isn;t what you want, and will fail to find any files if there is no `b1.txt` in your `$RUN_DIR` directory

To prevent the shell globbing a wildcard file pattern you just need to put it in quotes, so your command becomes

```
perl Test.pl 'b*.txt'
```

Beyond that, your program really needs improving. You should *always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the head of all your programs, and declare every variable at its point of first use; you should really use just the first element of `@ARGV` as your file pattern, instead of the whole array; and it is wrong to put scalar variables in quotes when you simply want their contents

Take a look at this refactoring of your original

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $run_dir="/home/ckhau/database/experiment/test";

my $pattern = "$run_dir/$ARGV[0]";

my $index = -999; 
my @files = glob $pattern;

foreach my $file (@files) {
  my $script = "perl abc.pl '$file'";
  system $script;
}
```

**Update**

If you *really* want to have multiple wildcard patterns as parameters to `Test.pl` then you must patch the `$run_dir` directory onto the beginning of each of them. The best way to do this is to employ the [`File::Spec`](https://metacpan.org/module/File%3a%3aSpec) module's `rel2abs` function. The complete script would look like this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Spec;

my $run_dir="/home/ckhau/database/experiment/test";

my $pattern = join ' ', map File::Spec->rel2abs($_, $run_dir), @ARGV;

my $index = -999;
my @files = glob $pattern;

foreach my $file (@files) {
  my $script = "perl abc.pl '$file'";
  system $script;
}
```

Comment: The one you have mentioned in the update is the one i actually want,I.e. i will have to give many wildcard patterns But i am not able to install these CPAN modules so is their any better way to do this without those modules.

Comment: +1 for suggestions to newbie to use 'use strict' and 'use warnings'

Comment: @unkaitha: Are you saying you can't install the CPAN modules because you don't have root on your machine?  If so, you can install modules to a non-system Perl area of your choice by following these instructions: http://linuxgazette.net/139/okopnik.html

Comment: @unkaitha: if you do get your personal CPAN library up and running, consider using the Readonly module.  I notice you put $RUN_DIR in all-caps...if you intend for that to be a constant you could "use Readonly;  Readonly $RUN_DIR => '/home/ckhau/database/experiment/test';"